# Which collection in java enables insterting between elements

Tags: java, list, collections

I would like to use colllection(List like one) in java which enables inserting between to elements?

Answer (score 5):

Collections that are derivative of List contain an add method that takes an index so you can do this. java.util.ArrayList is a common one...

Comment: Ok so how to turn a array into arrayList?NOT list

Comment: new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))

Comment: java.util.Arrays and java.util.Collections contain many static functions for doing redundant tasks of conversion and processing of these items.

Comment: ArrayList has not this kind of method, Vector has.

Answer (score 0):

Use [add method of List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)
to specify the position where you want to insert in a list

Answer (score 0):

Adding an element between elements is an optional operation, which by default in AbstractCollection is not implemented and throws a specific exception. Derived by AbstractCollection, [AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) was added with out of the box implementation for add(int, E) so any concrete implementation of AbstractList will have it.
 
More important, choose an implementation that fit your needs of performance regarding memory consumption, reads, writes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
The List interface has a function add(index,element) which adds an element at the specified index.

ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Java") ;
list.add("JSP") ;
list.add("STRUTS") ;
list.add("EJB") ;

list.add(2,"C++");
```

Answer (score 0):

The list interface declares a function add(int index, E element).
The ArrayList, LinkedList class has implementations for the above method. So can use either one of the above as per your requirement to add an element in between.

List os = new ArrayList();
os.add('Windows');
os.add('Linux');
os.add('Mac');
os.add(1,'Android')

Android will be added at the 1st index of the list i:e will be the 2nd element as index begins with 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the add(int index, Integer element) function of the list.

In this function, you can specifically put the element in the range of list using the index value.

Here is the sample:

```
List<Integer> sampleList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   sampleList.add(1);
   sampleList.add(2);
   sampleList.add(3); //sampleList now contains {1,2,3}
```

Now if you want to put it between 1 and 2.

```
   sampleList.add(1,4); //sampleList now contains {1,4,2,3}
```

We put the value 4 between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

Array List is the best way to Insert/Update/Delete like operations easily.

And also you can use Linked List for that but it is used mostly for large data.